# Can't create admin user with Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: mac, macos, user-account

My girlfriend did a mistake when she deleted her session login! But, she has only one session login. Now, we can't connect to the Mac because we don't have any access... So I booted to Recovery Mode, opened Terminal.app and tried to execute:

```
dscl . -create /Users/mynewuser
```

But it doesn't work ... Terminal said : create: Invalid Path

```
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

What can I do please ?

Comment: Can we try to clarify the problem before we look into possible solutions? By session login you mean a user account? And there was only one account on the Mac and it somehow got removed?